# Javascript Tic Tac Toe Game does not display Tie whenever win combos are not chosen

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, javascript-objects, iife

I am creating a Tic Tac Toe game using javascript's immediately invoked function element(IIFE). So far, I have managed to create the game board with CSS and HTML and have also managed to get game play that identifies the winner based on the sign. I have also been able to create a reset function. My problem however is that I cannot figure out how to program the logic to display a tie when none of the combinations are found. What often happens is whenever I try to program the logic for a tie, it displays tie on first click on the game board. Can someone please help me sort this out!

```
    const gameBoard = (() =>{        
        const sectors = document.querySelectorAll(".sector");
        
        let sector = Array.from(sectors);
        const winner = [
            [0,1,2],
            [3,4,5],
            [6,7,8],
            [0,3,6],
            [1,4,7],
            [2,5,8],
            [0,4,8],
            [2,4,6]
        ];

        let choice = "X"; 
                
        const gamePlay = () =>{
            const count = () => sector.forEach((val, index)=>{
                val.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    if(val.textContent === choice){
                        index += 1;
                    }else{
                        index = 0;
                    }
                })
                
            })
            const move = () =>{                
                sector.forEach((mark)=>{
                    mark.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                        if(mark.textContent === ""){                                            
                        choice = choice === "X"?"O":"X";
                        mark.textContent = choice;
                        gameWinner();
                        }                                               
                    })
                })                
            }
            move()
            const resetGame = () =>{
                const reset = document.querySelector("#reset");
                reset.addEventListener('click',()=>{
                    sector.forEach((mark) =>{
                        mark.textContent = "";
                    })
                })
            }
            resetGame();           
            const gameWinner = () =>{
                winner.forEach((combo)=>{
                    let checkWinner = combo.every(idx =>
                        sector[idx].textContent === choice)
                    if(checkWinner){
                        alert(choice + " has won!");
                    }else if(count() <= winner.length && !checkWinner){
                        alert('tie');
                    }
                })                               
            }            
        }
        const players = (player1, player2, machine)=>{
            
        }
        return {gamePlay};       
    })();
    gameBoard.gamePlay();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
        <script src="game.js" defer></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header id="title">Tic-Tac-Toe</header>
        <main>
            <!--<div id="playerSelection">
                <p>Select Your Mark</p>
                <button id="x">X</button><button id="o">O</button>
            </div>-->
            <div id="board">
                <div id = "one" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "two" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "three" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "four" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "five" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "six" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "seven"class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "eight" class="sector"></div>
                <div id = "nine" class="sector"></div>
            </div>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>            
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
#title{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#board{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
    grid-gap:10px;
    background-color: darkblue;
    width:320px;
    height:320px;
}
.sector{
    background-color: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
#playerSelection{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
main{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Please include the code that attempts to detect a tie.  Readers need to see if it includes a count of moves since the game started, or counts the number of unmarked squares after each turn in order to work out what is wrong with it.

Comment: Hello traktor. I have since added a count function to try and trigger a tie alert in the gameWinner function. I have added this to the original code.

Comment: why not create a list of possible move and check if there is a winning move in them ?
you only have 82 possibilities after first player, so it's not to much to process i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- `count` is binding event listeners. It is not counting anything. Something gets done when these events are triggered (when clicked), but that is useless. The `index` increment will not have any effect as this variable is never used for anything other then incrementing and resetting. Finally, `count()` always returns `undefined` because that is what `forEach` is designed to return. Instead define a function `boardIsFull`:

  ```
  const boardIsFull = () => sector.every((val) => val.textContent != "");
  ```
- `gameWinner` is calling `count()` for *every* combination. Surely the state of a tie is not dependent on which combo is being verified, so the check for a tie should only happen once. Here is how you could define this function:

  ```
  const gameWinner = () => {
      let checkWinner = winner.find((combo) => 
          combo.every(idx => sector[idx].textContent === choice)
      );
      if (checkWinner) {
          alert(choice + " has won!");
      } else if(boardIsFull()) {
          alert('tie');
      }
  };
  ```

You should further improve your code to avoid that the game continues after a player has already made a winning combo.

You can then add more features, like an algorithm that calculates a move so you can play a "computer" opponent. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417503/5459839) for such an implementation.

Comment: Thank you trincot! This helped considerably. Now I can move on to adding other features as you had alluded to in your response. Thanks again!