# JS Tic Tac Toe disable click after the cell is taken

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, nodelist

```
let pos = document.querySelectorAll('[data-cell]');
let winPositions = [
    ['0', '1', '2'],
    ['3', '4', '5'],
    ['6', '7', '8'],
    ['0', '3', '6'],
    ['1', '4', '7'],
    ['2', '5', '8'],
    ['0', '4', '8'],
    ['2', '4', '6']
];
let currentPlayer = true;
let xPlayer = [];
let oPlayer = [];

function showGame() {
    document.getElementById('game-board').style.display = 'block';
    let buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (let button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            let gameMode = this.getAttribute('data-mode');
            runGame(gameMode);
        })
    }
}

function runGame(gameMode) {
    if (gameMode === 'vsPlayer') {
        vsPlayer();
    } else if (gameMode === 'vsCPU') {
        vsCpu();
    }
}

function vsPlayer() {
    pos.forEach(cell => {
        cell.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            let currentCell = event.target;
            let position = currentCell.dataset.cell;
            currentPlayer === true ? xPlayer.push(position) : oPlayer.push(position);
            currentCell.classList.add(currentPlayer ? 'x' : 'o');
            currentPlayer = !currentPlayer;
            if (xPlayer.length >= 3) {
                checkWinner();
            }
        })
    })
}


function vsCpu() {
    let cpu = Math.floor(Math.random() * pos.length);

}

function checkWinner() {
    winPositions.forEach(winPos => {
        const xWon = winPos.every(pos => xPlayer.includes(pos))
        const oWon = winPos.every(pos => oPlayer.includes(pos))

        if (xWon) {
            let xScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('xScore').innerText);

            document.getElementById('startAgain').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('text').textContent = "X Won!";

            document.getElementById('xScore').innerText = xScore + 1;
            restartGame();
        }
        if (oWon) {
            let oScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('oScore').innerText);

            document.getElementById('startAgain').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('text').textContent = "O Won!";

            document.getElementById('oScore').innerText = oScore + 1;
            restartGame();
        } else if (xPlayer.length >= 5) {
            document.getElementById('startAgain').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('text').textContent = "It's a Draw!";
            restartGame()
        }
    })
}

function restartGame() {
    document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('startAgain').style.display = 'none';
        currentPlayer = true;
        xPlayer = [];
        oPlayer = [];
        pos.forEach(cell => {
            cell.classList.remove('x', 'o');
        })
    })
    showGame();
}
```

I have added and implemented new methods and changed few things around thanks to everyones advice. Now i dont know how to disable click, so player cant press on a cell thats already taken and if player presses on vsPlayer method twice it just places circles. The vsCPU method is still empty, it will be an option later on.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the page with `location.reload()`?

Comment: This isnt a full answer but resetting state of something that has been mutated back to its original state is often the hard way, and a source of bugs. You could just destroy the entire DOM node that represents the whole game and build it up again. If that HTML that represents the game comes from the server, you could rewrite it such that its created on the client side, or you could keep a copy of it around in memory when the page loads. Then use this copy to overwrite everything and setup the game from scratch.

Comment: Or you could just reload the page as @MichaelM says :D. Depends on your needs

Comment: `showGame` is not defined; `vsPlayerMode` and `vsCpuMode` are never used; the first value that `pos` gets is never used (it first is an array, but then is overwritten to be a DOM element). There are more closing braces than opening, ... I stopped looking further. Please provide code that can be run -- preferably as a runnable snippet inside your question (use toolbar).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. i have a choice of vs cpu and 2player game which is yet to be implemented and probably the whole code need reshuffling, dont know wheter to manipulate the DOM element or create new array. At least you guys have helped me with what issues i have in the code. Thank you

Comment: There still is too much wrong: you are binding event listeners repeatedly; there is no check that a chosen cell is actually not already taken; the cpu move is not played; the cpu move is only generated when user choses game mode -- it should be generated after each player move; ...etc. Your question about disabling the click seems premature as you have more fundamental problems to solve first. There are many implementations in JavaScript you could take inspiration from, like one of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417503/5459839)

Answer (score 0):

You could reset the entire state of the game, however in most use cases it is a much better idea to use [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) instead to reload/refresh the page. All variables and the DOM will be reset, so if you need to persist some state (such as total games won/lost) you should use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage).