# How to add minimax algorithm to my tic tac toe game in js?

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

having issues implementing minimax code, the other codes I came across seemed hard to grasp, can someone tell me  how to integrate algorithm into my app?  I tried creating board for empty spaces define human/computer function, run the code on the turn fun, but yeah I created a hot mess, and used my git log to rewind, heres my code

I low key feel the issue lies in the structure of my app manifested in the lack of board variable, emptyspaces functions, minimax logic , or in the way I am integrating my logic with my other functions ,

```js
const x_class = "x";
const circle_class = "circle";
const cellElement = document.querySelectorAll("[data-cell]");
const winningMessageElement = document.getElementById("winningMessage");
const winningCombination = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6],
];
const board = document.getElementById("board");
let circleTurn;
const winningTextMessageElement = document.querySelector(
  "[data-winning-message-text]"
);

const reStartButton = document.getElementById("restartButton");
const optionX = document.getElementById("optionx");
const optionO = document.getElementById("optiono");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitButton");
const selection_X = document.getElementById("xOption");
const selection_O = document.getElementById("oOption");
const startForm = document.getElementById("startForm");

optionX.addEventListener("click", optionHandler);
optionO.addEventListener("click", optionHandler);
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", submitHandler);
reStartButton.addEventListener("click", startGame);

function optionHandler(e) {
  optionX.classList.remove("optionButtonStyle2");
  optionX.classList.add("optionButtonStyle");
  optionO.classList.remove("optionButtonStyle2");
  optionO.classList.add("optionButtonStyle");
  e.currentTarget.classList.remove("optionButtonStyle");
  e.currentTarget.classList.add("optionButtonStyle2");
}

function submitHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (selection_O.checked) {
    circleTurn = true;
    startForm.classList.add("hide");
    board.classList.add("show");
  } else if (selection_X.checked) {
    circleTurn = false;
    startForm.classList.add("hide");
    board.classList.add("show");
  } else {
    alert("please select an option");
  }
  startGame();
}

function startGame() {
  cellElement.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.classList.remove(x_class);
    cell.classList.remove(circle_class);
    cell.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    cell.addEventListener("click", handleClick, { once: true });
  });
  setBoardHoverClass();

  winningMessageElement.classList.remove("show");
}

function handleClick(e) {
  const cell = e.target;
  const currentClass = circleTurn ? circle_class : x_class;
  placeMark(cell, currentClass);
  if (checkWin(currentClass)) {
    endGame(false);
  } else if (isDraw()) {
    endGame(true);
  } else {
    swapTurns();
    setBoardHoverClass();
  }
}
function isDraw() {
  return [...cellElement].every((cell) => {
    return (
      cell.classList.contains(x_class) || cell.classList.contains(circle_class)
    );
  });
}

function endGame(draw) {
  if (draw) {
    winningTextMessageElement.innerText = "Tie!";
  } else {
    winningTextMessageElement.innerText = `${circleTurn ? "O's" : "X's"} Win!`;
  }
  winningMessageElement.classList.add("show");
}

function placeMark(cell, currentClass) {
  cell.classList.add(currentClass);
}

function swapTurns() {
  circleTurn = !circleTurn;
}

function setBoardHoverClass() {
  board.classList.remove(x_class);
  board.classList.remove(circle_class);
  if (circleTurn) {
    board.classList.add(circle_class);
  } else {
    board.classList.add(x_class);
  }
}

function checkWin(currentClass) {
  return winningCombination.some((combination) => {
    return combination.every((index) => {
      return cellElement[index].classList.contains(currentClass);
    });
  });
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --cell-size: 100px;
  --mark-size: calc(var(--cell-size) * 0.9);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.formStyle {
  background-color: rgb(236, 226, 221);
  max-width: 30%;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.headerStyle {
  color: #10213b !important;
}

.optionButtonStyle {
  background-color: #10213b !important;
  padding: 10px 70px !important;
  color: white !important;
}

.optionButtonStyle:hover {
  background-color: #183867 !important;
}
.submitButton {
  background-color: #10213b !important;
  padding: 10px 30px !important;
}

.submitButton:hover {
  background-color: #183867 !important;
  padding: 10px 30px !important;
}

.optionButtonStyle2 {
  background-color: orange !important;
  padding: 10px 70px !important;
  color: #183867 !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
}

.boardStyle {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)),
    url("image/tic-tac-toe_1706536926613.jpg");

  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.board {
  display: /*grid;*/ none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
}
.show {
  display: grid;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  min-width: var(--cell-size);
  height: var(--cell-size);
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cell:first-child,
.cell:nth-child(2),
.cell:nth-child(3) {
  border-top: none;
}

.cell:first-child,
.cell:nth-child(4),
.cell:nth-child(7) {
  border-left: none;
}

.cell:nth-child(3),
.cell:nth-child(6),
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  border-right: none;
}
.cell:nth-child(7),
.cell:nth-child(8),
.cell:nth-child(9) {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.cell.x::before,
.cell.x::after,
.cell.circle::before,
.cell.circle::after {
  background-color: pink;
}

.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
  background-color: pink;
}

.cell.x::before,
.cell.x::after,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.board.x .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(var(--mark-size) * 0.15);
  height: var(--mark-size);
}

.cell.x::before,
.board.x .cell:hover::before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.cell.x::after,
.board.x .cell:hover::after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.cell.circle::before,
.cell.circle::after,
.cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before,
.cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: var(--mark-size);
  height: var(--mark-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.cell.circle::before,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::before {
  width: var(--mark-size);
  height: var(--mark-size);
}
.cell.circle::after,
.board.circle .cell:not(.x):not(.circle):hover::after {
  width: calc(var(--mark-size) * 0.7);
  height: calc(var(--mark-size) * 0.7);
  background-color: /*white; #122b31;*/ #060f1d;
}

.cell.x,
.cell.circle {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.winning-message {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: pink;
  font-size: 5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.winning-message button {
  font-size: 3rem;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 70px; /* Combine the padding values into a single declaration */
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #081425;
}

.winning-message button:hover {
  background-color: #081425;
  color: pink;
  border-color: white;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in, color 0.2s ease-in,
    border-color 0.3s ease-in;
}

.winning-message.show {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) and (max-width: 1379px) {
  .formStyle {
    background-color: rgb(236, 226, 221);
    max-width: 50%;
    min-height: 45vh;
  }

  .submitButton {
    background-color: #10213b !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .optionButtonStyle {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .optionButtonStyle2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 899px) {
  .formStyle {
    background-color: rgb(236, 226, 221);
    max-width: 80%;
    min-height: 45vh;
    overflow: none;
  }

  .submitButton {
    background-color: #10213b !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .optionButtonStyle {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .optionButtonStyle2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
  .formStyle {
    background-color: rgb(236, 226, 221);
    max-width: 90%;
    min-height: 45vh;
  }

  .submitButton {
    background-color: #10213b !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    overflow: none;
  }

  .optionButtonStyle {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: none;
  }
  .optionButtonStyle2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: none;
  }

  :root {
    --cell-size: 60px;
    --mark-size: calc(var(--cell-size) * 0.9);
  }
  .winning-message {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: pink;
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .winning-message button {
    font-size: 1rem;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 70px; /* Combine the padding values into a single declaration */
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #081425;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="boardStyle container-fluid">
      <div class="formStyle" id="startForm">
        <h1 class="text-center display-1 fw-medium headerStyle">Tic Tac Toe</h1>
        <form action="" class="text-center">
          <h2 class="text-center my-4 headerStyle">Choose a Symbol:</h2>
          <div class="mt-4">
            <label
              class="btn rounded-0 btn-lg optionButtonStyle mx-3"
              id="optionx"
            >
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="option"
                id="xOption"
                value="x"
                class="visually-hidden"
              />
              <span class="fw-medium display-6">X</span>
            </label>
            <label
              class="btn rounded-0 btn-lg optionButtonStyle mx-3"
              id="optiono"
            >
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="option"
                id="oOption"
                value="o"
                class="visually-hidden"
              />
              <span class="fw-medium display-6">O</span>
            </label>
          </div>
          <button
            class="btn btn-lg text-center rounded-0 text-white submitButton mt-5"
            id="submitButton"
          >
            Start Game
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="board" id="board">
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
        <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
      </div>
      <div class="winning-message" id="winningMessage">
        <div data-winning-message-text></div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg rounded-0" id="restartButton">Restart</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"lack of board variable"*: in other words, you mix presentation code with logic. This is bad practice. You should separate logic from DOM operations. In my opinion, you should not try to just work with this and get minimax working. For a working implementation without fancy user-interface, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64882717/5459839).

Comment: I checked that code it was mostly logic, but how did they link that logic with html css file, that I don't understand

Comment: The HTML is linked at the top of `main`, and the `display` function writes to those elements, setting their text, and their CSS class.

Comment: thanks appreciate the help , it's basically separation logic from presentation , definitely makes it easier to understand